# How do i get the value of a select menu after pressing a button? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a message with 2 action rows. One contains a select menu, and the other contains a button. How do i get the selected item from the select menu when the button is pressed?

I have this following code so far:

```
if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId == 'deleteTask') {
            console.log("Deleting task!")
            console.log(taskName)
            delete(taskName)
        }
 }
```

I need the variable taskName to be the selected option in a select menu. The select menu is in the same message as the button, and it has the custom Id 'selectTask'. This is the code for the select menu and button menu:

```
const row = new MessageActionRow() // Define action row
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu() // Add task selector
                    .setCustomId('selectTask')
                    .setPlaceholder('Select an assignment..')
                    .addOptions(choices),
            );

const btnrow = new MessageActionRow() // Define action row
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('deleteTask')
                    .setLabel("Delete task")
                    .setStyle("DANGER"),
            );
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO ! Show us what you have tried so you're most likely to get an answer. Just a bit of code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a message component collector you just need to get the first value from that collector.
Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/SelectMenuInteraction?scrollTo=values

```
collectorInteraction.values[0]
```

*Change collectorInteraction to whatever you named your collector parameter*

If you still need to make a component collector, maybe visit these 2 websites:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/InteractionCollector

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

Answer (score 0):

I suggested an edit but wasn't logged in at the time. discord.js.org has been updated the new link is https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/InteractionCollector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34562662)